Hyper-V external network is slowing down my entire home internet
I've been facing this issue for a while now. I have 3 PCs and 1 NAS storage device (Synology DiskStation DS224+), with each PC running around 10 VMs. I am using Hyper-V and connecting them to the NAS device using an external network. For some reason, my internet speed is getting extremely slow, and my network load is very high. This is the network switch I am using: TP-Link TL-SG1008D 8-Port Gigabit Ethernet. I'm not sure what I might be doing wrong. I read an article suggesting that I should turn off:

Large Send Offload Version 2 (IPv4)
Large Send Offload Version 2 (IPv6)
Recv Segment Coalescing (IPv4)
Recv Segment Coalescing (IPv6)

It seemed to work for a while, but now I’m facing the same issue again—everything is getting extremely laggy, and I’m not sure what to do.
More Notes:

Each VM is only using 20%-25% CPU and around 50%-70% memory.
The VMs are connecting to a shared folder located on my NAS, a Synology DiskStation DS224+. I don’t feel this is the issue, but I’m mentioning it here just in case.
Internet speed/upload when VMs are turned: 550 Mbps and upload speed 290 Mbps, When the VMs are turned on, even the internet on my mobile connected to Wi-Fi can’t load Instagram reels, for example. I’m not sure why this is happening, I’m testing with all my VMs turned on, and they’re still reaching that speed, but everything is super laggy. It feels like something is interrupting the connection, as if it’s going off and on for some reason.
I am using the VMs for machine learning. They are interacting with a shared folder on my NAS, updating a very small 1GB database stored there, and performing small read/write operations.
I’m not using any tools to monitor things. Can you recommend one, if possible?
I was facing this issue even before getting the NAS. Back then, two PCs were connected to my main PC (PC1) to access the shared folder in it through the switch, so the switch might be part of the problem. I think 'saturating the network' is likely what’s happening. Even when the internet speed tests show it’s still fast, everything feels super laggy, and all my devices at home are slowing down when accessing the internet.
My VMs Purpose: I’m currently using the VMs for data preprocessing and model training in a distributed machine learning project. Each VM accesses datasets from the shared NAS folder, allowing for parallel processing and speeding up the model training process.
This is my home switch model "Huawei EchoLife HG8145V5"
I'm using the internet on my VMs to access online datasets, APIs, and updates for machine learning libraries as part of my distributed ML project. Do you guys think this could be what's choking my network?
I am mapping the shared folder using letter inside every VM and PC that is being shared from the NAS device

My home network setup
there are 2 other people living with me who are connected to the main home network, but I didn’t include them in my diagram.
My NAS Resource Monitor
My main home router
My main home router recourses
